# Trying to change the style in "Select an Option" dropdown of Woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, datastax-astra

I am trying to change the "Select an option" text's style, of WooCommerce checkout page, in bolder because it is faded and I get an accessibility error when scanned with WAVE.

I have tried this CSS but nothing changes, could you indicate me where am I mistaking?

```
Select a category {
  color: #cccccc
  
}
span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single {
  color: #000000;
}
span.select2-selection__placeholder {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Or if there is an other CSS to do it?

The site is [www.defkalionsa.gr](http://www.defkalionsa.gr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the below css:

```
.select2-selection__placeholder {
    font-weight:bold; /* for your "bolder" request" */
    color:black; /* better than gray for accessibility */
}
```

if that does not work, you should clear browser cache, and check if other style declarations are [taking precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).
You can temporarily add "!important" to overwrite other declarations.

```
.select2-selection__placeholder {
    font-weight:bold!important;
    color:black!important;
}
```